# How to avoid multiple function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have click event function to create a new dom elements. Basically, every time I click a button. It allows create a new hyperlink tag.

I also want to have a functionality that if new created hyperlink clicked, I want to call different function.

Please have a look following code,

```
var id = 1;

$('#create').on('click', function() {
   id ++ 
   $('.players').append('<a href="#" class="new" data-id='+ id + '> ' + id + 'player</a>');

   getId() 

 });

function getId() {
   $('.new').on('click', function() {
   var id = $(this).data('id')
   alert(id);
});
}
```

My problem is I don't want to run `getId()` function everytime I clicked a button, But if I run `getId()` function alone, new created hyperlink won't effent that functionality.

Is anyway I can call `getId()` function once. and It still going to effect a new created hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegation, then there is no need to attach the event handler function every time you append. Remove your `getId()` function and replace it with a delegated `on()` method:

```
var id = 1;

$('#create').on('click', function () {
    id++;
    $('.players').append('<a href="#" class="new" data-id=' + id + '> ' + id + 'player</a>');
});

$('.players').on('click', '.new', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id')
    alert(id);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ApK8/)

Comment: I thought so - I thought I misread when I saw C-link's answer. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to use the function only for once.

```
function getId() {
   $('.new').one('click', function() {
   var id = $(this).data('id')
   alert(id);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, the OP will still have to call `getId()` for each element that is appended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for `dynamic elements` like,

```
$(function(){
    var id = 1;
    $('#create').on('click', function() {
       id ++;
       $('.players').append('<a href="#" class="new" data-id='+id+'>'+id+'player</a>');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.new', function() {
  //use ^ document or your parent element players
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       alert(id);
    });
});
```